# The read line variable returns a blank when surrounded with double quotes

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to simply read in a file, looking for a specific line in that file. I am somewhat new to bash. Below is a simplified version:

```bsh
removeIgnoreEntry() {
    start=0
    while read line; do

        echo "$line"

        if [ "$line" = "ignore_profiles" ]; then 
            echo "Profile Start"
            start=1
        elif [ "$start" = 1 ]; then 
            if [ "$line" = "$1" ]; then 
                echo "Line found!"
            fi 
        fi 
    done < "$FILE" 
}
```

The strange behavior is the 4th line (`echo "$line"`) where `echo` does not display anything to the console. However, if I add some characters before `$line`, it displays just fine (e.g. `echo "My line: $line"`).

I have no idea why, and this is - I believe - why the `if` statement just after the `echo` fails to recognize when it finds the line with `ignore_profiles`.

I cannot find information about this anywhere, probably because I don't have the right keywords.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash Does this help explain the issue.

Comment: @JasonCroyle Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Is the file you are parsing a Windows text file? Could it have windows-style line endings?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in that, at least not with the `echo`. With Windows-style CRLF line endings the comparisons wouldn't match, but the `echo` should still work. Show a full working script, how you run it, and a sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Does your input file contain anything that `echo` could interpret as an option?  like `-n`?

Try `printf "%s\n" "$line"` instead of `echo "$line"`.

Also, use `read -r` instead of just `read`.

BTW, your entire while loop could be replaced with something like this, using  awk in your shell function:

```
removeIgnoreEntry() {

  awk -v search="$1" '{print}
      /^ignore_profiles$/ { start=1; print "Profile Start" };
      start == 1 && $0 == search { print "Line Found!" }' "$FILE"
}
```

You could return start from the awk script if you need it with `END { exit start }`, which will return an exit code of either 0 or 1 depending on the value of awk's start variable.

```
removeIgnoreEntry() {

  awk -v search="$1" '{print}
      /^ignore_profiles$/ { start=1; print "Profile Start" };
      start == 1 && $0 == search { print "Line Found!" }
      END {exit start}' "$FILE"

  start=$?    # get the exit code of the awk script into sh's $start variable.
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if either of these are exactly what you want, mostly because I can't figure out what it is you're trying to do with the nested ifs and elif.